# Пагинатор Django работает не правильно, если записи (данные) поступают через API, без запроса в базу данных

Tags: python, django, api

views.py

```
    limit = request.GET.get('limit')
    limit = int(limit) if limit else None
    context['limit'] = limit

    page = request.GET.get('page')  
    page = int(page) if page els
    context['page'] = page

    data_posting_orders = api.posting_orders(api_session, page=page, limit=limit) #
    summary_count = api.get_summary(api_session).get('holder_summary')['count']


objects = data_posting_orders.get('transactions') # получение всех данных по api
paginator = Paginator(objects, 15)
try:
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages)
context['page_obj'] = page_obj
```

index.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="posting-orders" class="order-column table-hover table-bordered nowrap"
                               bgcolor="#f0ffff" style="width:100%">
                            {% include 'includes/_header_table_posting_orders.html' %}
                            <tbody>
                            {% for order in page_obj %}
                                {% include 'includes/_body_table_posting_orders.html' %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-success font-weight-bold" colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Итого:
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-danger font-weight-bold" style="text-align: right"></th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                        <nav hidden aria-label="...">
                            <ul style="" class="pagination justify-content-end">
                                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo; Первая</a></li>
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                             href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Пред</a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                                    {% if page == page_obj.number %}
                                        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link"
                                                                        href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {% elif page > page_obj.number|add:-3 and page < page_obj.number|add:3 %}
                                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                                 href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                             href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">След</a></li>
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                             href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Последняя({{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }})</a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
```

Проблема в том, что пагинатор получает весь список, а потом делит его на страницы. И я думаю, что его работа должна заключаться в том, как получить записи из API, не все сразу, а некоторые из них.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пагинатор работает не правильно, долго. Данные получаю по api из стороннего сервера. В пагинатор  
paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25)
в contact_list передаю objects (который получает по api 36K записей) и он сначала его получает а потом делит на страницы. Почему так ? должно же приходить из api по 15 записей а не все каждый раз

Comment: 1. Пишите на русском, так как вопрос находится в русской версии stackoverflow. 2. Опишите вашу проблему подробнее **в вопросе**, а не в комментариях